# Deep Learning - Candlestick Question (CNN Model)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, candlestick-chart

I am new to Deep Learning and just have a question if the method I am using is correct.

Also, if anybody has suggestions on what to change on the model creation it would also be appreciated.

[graphs look similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG0w2.jpg)

I am using a CNN model to train candlesticks based on 'buy', sell', and 'do trade' pictures that look similar to the attached picture. (tried different number of bars but results where similar)

I based the code of this post:

https://towardsdatascience.com/making-a-i-that-looks-into-trade-charts-62e7d51edcba

I have made a few changes but kept the model training code similar (small changes did not produce significant accuracy)

```
# Input the size of your sample images
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
nb_filters1 = 32
nb_filters2 = 32
nb_filters3 = 64
conv1_size = 3
conv2_size = 2
conv3_size = 5
pool_size = 2
# We have 2 classes, buy and sell
classes_num = 3
batch_size = 128
lr = 0.001
chanDim =3

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters1, conv1_size, conv1_size, border_mode ='same', input_shape=(img_height, img_width , 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size)))

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters2, conv2_size, conv2_size, border_mode ="same"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), dim_ordering='th'))

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters3, conv3_size, conv3_size, border_mode ='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), dim_ordering='th'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(classes_num, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer=optimizers.rmsprop(),
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    #rescale=1. / 255,
    horizontal_flip=False)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    #rescale=1. / 255,
    horizontal_flip=False)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    #shuffle=True,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    #shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')
```

With this, I get an accuracy of 38% and if I remove the 'no trade' option, I get an accuracy of 52%.

Before training and after training does not improve accuracy drastically, that is why I am assuming the settings are not 100%

.

When predicting, the results always lean to one side (52% buy, 48% sell) and don't change much after a few hundred images.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your three options are "buy", "sell", and "no trade". The reason why it jumps to 52% is because it's differentiating between 2 instead of 3 options.

With regards to the lower than expected accuracy, I recommend changing the loss to `Adam`. Also possibly move the dropout layer to the middle of the network. I have found success adding a `dropout = .2` after each pooling layer. This way nodes are dropped throughout the network which allows for more "diversity" in node paths taken.